# Kotlin: Platform declaration clash

Tags: java, kotlin, jvm

I am a beginner in Kotlin and I am trying to make a basic person class with the following code:

```
class Person(_firstName: String, _lastName: String, _age: Int){

    val firstName: String = _firstName
    val lastName: String = _lastName
    var age: Int = _age

    fun setAge(newAge: Int){
        age = newAge
    }
}
```

I wanted to add some basic methods to my class such as getters and setters. When I created the setAge function and try to compile I get the following errors:

```
Error:(4, 5) Kotlin: Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (setAge(I)V):
    fun <set-age>(<set-?>: Int): Unit defined in Person
    fun setAge(newAge: Int): Unit defined in Person

Error:(6, 5) Kotlin: Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (setAge(I)V):
    fun <set-age>(<set-?>: Int): Unit defined in Person
    fun setAge(newAge: Int): Unit defined in Person
```

I am new to Kotlin and have absolutely no idea what the issue is. I have some experience in Java and never really ran into any problems creating (almost) trivial classes like this.

Could someone please explain in a beginner friendly way what exactly is the problem here and what I can do to resolve this issue/avoid it in the future. Thank you.

Comment: You need to understand Kotins concept of "properties". Read docs here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is

```
fun setAge(newAge: Int){
    age = newAge
}
```

When you declare

```
var age: Int = _age
```

it will generate a `setAge` method for you so what you are supposed to do instead is to override the setter for `age`. In your case, however, this is not necessary since the generated setter will do the same as your `setAge` method.

You can also refer to the [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html) to learn more.